# single word adjective for a great or large/expansive task

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm trying to think of the word that means "a large task, almost more than is easily handled, but not unpleasant." The sentence that I am using it in is this:

> I know that the number of topics and information within each topic to be covered seems to be a/an _______________ task, we will work through them as we are able.

*Arduous* and *Herculean* don't seem quite right.  It's not insurmountable.

Comment: "Yuge", obviously.

Comment: @HotLicks damn! you're fast! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEA33bAXyNM

Comment: I'm writing this to a 92 year old lady.  Not sure she would get the gist of "yuge".  Appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Also, considered these? http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/herculean

Comment: A number of topics is not a task. Dealing with them is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word for something difficult or nearly impossible to achieve](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62299/word-for-something-difficult-or-nearly-impossible-to-achieve)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're looking for "daunting".

> I know that the number of topics and information within each topic to be covered seems to be a daunting task, but we will work through them as we are able.

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***extensive***.

> I know that the number of topics and information within each topic to
>   be covered seems to be ***extensive***; we will work through
>   them as we are able to.

ODO:

> **[extensive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/extensive)** *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1.1** Large in amount or scale
>
> ‘I have a fairly extensive amount of work done on the subject, and a
>   number of links that are worth following.’