# What is the rare word that describes something that is impossible to attain yet it is still desired?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I have only run across this word twice in my life and it was used to describe something that was deeply desired by a person, yet for them it was impossible to ever attain. Therefore, the word in question described what this thing was to them. For example:

> "Given the problems with Dave's past, a healthy relationship with his dad is ___________. "

Comment: Although possibly too much in this case, look into "quixotic".  *"A quixotic quest. A quixotic crusade. After everything that has occurred, building a healthy relationship with his dad is probably  nothing more than a quixotic dream."*

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - here OP is asking for a rare word, the  supposed “duplicate” question doesn’t answer this trait of the question. Please read carefully before close-voting.

Comment: @user3850720 I virtually always do. The duplicate subsumes this question; I specifically checked that 'chimera' was suggested there. Please don't trivialise the site.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - chimera was just one suggestion, other interesting ones might have come up, had the question not been improperly put on hold.

Comment: @user3850720 Then they could / should have also come up at the duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Could/should ?  it’s a close mania issue. A problem  on this site.

Comment: OP has accepted your answer. So it's the only answer they were interested in {**the** rare word that describes something that is impossible to attain yet it is still desired}, which makes the question too narrowly scoped for ELU anyway. Other possibilities for a more general audience (pipe dream / wishful thinking / fantasy / pie in the sky) are given at the duplicate. And [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62299/word-for-something-difficult-or-nearly-impossible-to-achieve).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - This is interesting discussion. I actually searched the site for a similar question for quite a while before posting my own. Maybe this site isn't very intuitive if a duplicate existed but I was unable locate it with a simple search.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Also when you marked my question as a duplicate, you didn't include a link to the question that was previously answered. This doesn't help either. Finally, you refer to the other question as "the duplicate" but you marked my question as the duplicate. Seems sloppy for a website about English Language & Usage.

Comment: The reasons the site is hard to search are (a) people sometimes supply totally unhelpful titles and (b) it is getting very large, unnecessarily so because people keep adding duplicate questions. // The link is given automatically with duplicate closures. You missed it. // There has been a discussion about the dual role of 'duplicate'. It was considered acceptable. This time, it is understandable that you missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chimera:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chimera#translations)
​

> a hope or dream that is extremely unlikely ever to come true:
> *Is the ideal of banishing hunger throughout the world just a chimera?*

(Cambridge Dictionary)